# Tomcat responds 200 instead of 405

Tags: kotlin, tomcat, openshift, ktor

I found quite a lot of reversed problems when application or server responded with 405 for endpoint when it should with 200. But my problem is other. When I call endpoint with unsuported method for example use Delete instead of GET I receive 200

I have a kotlin backend built on ktor, running on Tomcat.

I have endpoint with httpMethod GET, it works fine. But when I call it with for example DELETE or PUT I get response 200, with only partial headers and no body . This situation occures only when app is served from Open shift, when I launcher it locally from InteliJ with Tomcat embedded, when I call delete I get 405 - Method not implemented which is ok. I don't understand why it acts different.

Tomcat embedded 9.0.79

Standalone 9.0.50

Web.xml for standalone is standard for ktor

I confirmed it is no open shift routing issue by curl'ing localhost from PODs console.

Sorry for no code snippets but corporate rules forbid me.

Comment: Are you sure nothing else responds with 200 when your app is served from OpenShift?

Comment: If corporate rules forbid sharing debugging details, this might be the wrong place to ask for help: Please see [ask] - we're looking for _specific_ questions that are actionable. Best with a [mcve].

Comment: That's why I'm asking, I'm not sure what generates this response, as app doesn't leave any evidence of this. No log, no console entry. Is there any chance that tomcat responds by default on any call with empty 200? It is red hat container jboss webserver 5.6